# Azure VM Scale Set Autoscale dynamic instance count

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, autoscaling

Is it possible to add dynamic number of instances in an Azure Virtual Machine Scaleset autoscale rule? As shown in the image, can I pass a variable for the instance count for scaling out?

[image]

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: What is the reason that you don't accept the answer and also do not ask more questions?

Comment: I'm waiting for a better answer. It is unfair to force people to accept your answers.

Comment: It's just an advice. And you didn't give any response. Otherwise, there is no better solution for it. But you can wait as you want.

Comment: I did mark your answer as useful - to your point that I did not give any response.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you cannot do it. When you do it, it will show the limitations:

[image]

Just imagine, we can't know when it will scale the instances so that we cannot know what is the time to set the variable with an exact number. So it must be a valid number without empty. And the number between 1 and 512 is a limitation set by Azure.